# Not able to cut files in ntfs drive

Tags: macos, ntfs

I recently purchased a md101 macbook pro model. I installed tuxera for ntfs read/write permission.

I can access my drive without any issues. I cut write to the drive, delete a file in the drive and copy from the drive.

But I am not able to cut(`cmd+X`) any files from the drive to my local.

Please let me know If I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1):

The Finder doesn't have a Cut command, as such.

Use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  to copy, then
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>    <kbd>C</kbd>  to simultaneously Cut from the previous location & paste to the new.

Alternatively, hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  whilst dragging from one partition to another to Move instead of Copy.